# Multithreading or Asynchronous for Python GTK/Socket Server/Data Writing

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Python, socket, multithreading and asynchronous programming. I'm wondering what is the best approach to implement a server that receives and sends data between a client such as a Unity3D game and plot out these data in a GUI using Python GTK while writing these data to a text file in real time. To make things a bit more complicated, the data comes from an Eyetracker which receives gaze data at the speed of 300 ms. Given these requirements, is it better to use threads or async? Moreover, should I be creating a UDP or TCP server to exchange the data?

If more information is needed, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use TCP. UDP are mostly used for things like video/audio streaming. That's not the case here.

As for `async` vs `thread` in Unity, I would suggest you go for with Thread. It is easier and you are guaranteed that your network code will not be slowing Unity down in any way.

> Unity3D game and plot out these data in a GUI using Python GTK

If you are receiving data from eye tracker, you should be able to plot the data with Unity. If your requirement is to use Python then it is still possible to make server/cleint connection between Unity and your Python App.